# Oracle query execution takes time when call through windows service

Tags: c#, .net, oracle

I have encountered an issue where, whenever I execute query or procedure through windows service or .NET web application it takes huge time to execute Ex: 30 min - 1:30 hour but when same query or procedure is executed using SQL Developer or SQLPLUS cmd prompt, time is reduced to 1 - 30 min.
I have asked DBA is there any program specific memory allocation being applied or not, he replies with issue is in your code.  I have tried searching for the issue could not get any thread to look into. Help or guidance would be much appreciated.

EDIT-1: I am using procedure to load data from staging to main table, No join or checking is applied on staging data,Ex:Insert into MainTable (col1,col2... colN) select col,col2..colN from staging_table,(only in one scenario we update existing data and insert new record but there also I have seen time difference between windows service and SQL developer).
When procedure is called using windows service for 1 batch it takes 30 min to 1:30 hr but same when called through SQL developer it gets complete within few minutes.
Below is c# code which call procedure in Loop// Batch wise data insertion.

```
while (rowfrom < TotalRows)
{ 
   try
    {
     lstparams = new List<OracleCommand>();
     lstparams.Add(DAL.AddOutParamOracle(_guid, "P_SessionId", OracleType.VarChar, ParameterDirection.Input));
     lstparams.Add(DAL.AddOutParamOracle(rowfrom, "p_RunningSrNo", OracleType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input));
     lstparams.Add(DAL.AddOutParamOracle(OracleUploadLimit, "p_BatchCount", OracleType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input));
 

     ds1Result = DAL.ExecuteDataSet("usp_I2EDRawToMain", lstparams);
    // In ExecuteDataSet function OracleDataAdapter class is used to execute procedure
     rowfrom += OracleUploadLimit;
     int v_HoldRunningSrNo = rowfrom > TotalRowsUploaded ? TotalRowsUploaded : rowfrom;
     bool isLastBatch = rowfrom > TotalRowsUploaded ? true : false;
     if (isLastBatch)
     {
        DAL.insertOracle("StagingToMain", fi.Name, "C", "File Uploaded Successfully from Staging to Main Table. Uploaded RowCount (" + v_HoldRunningSrNo.ToString() + "/" + TotalRows.ToString() + ") Error Count("+errorRecordCount.ToString()+")", _guid, "I", serviceType);
     }
     else
     {
        DAL.insertOracle("StagingToMain", fi.Name, "P", "Detail table data is being uploaded from Staging to Main Table. Uploaded RowCount (" + v_HoldRunningSrNo.ToString() + "/" + TotalRows.ToString() + ")  Error Count(" + errorRecordCount.ToString() + ")", _guid, "I", serviceType);
     }
 
    }
    catch (Exception ex1)
    {
        throw ex1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi there. I believe DBA is right - the problem resides definitely somewhere on c# side. Can you add it to the query too please?

Comment: Can you describe what the "query or procedure" is doing?  If you're running a query, does the query return a lot of data?  When you're running in SQL Developer, are you measuring the time required for SQL Developer to show you the first row?  Or the time required to fetch the last row (this difference generally gets larger as the number of rows being returned increases).  Are you making a single procedure call?  Calling a procedure a bunch of times inside a loop?  Calling a procedure that has a `sys_refcursor` as an `out` parameter and fetching a million rows?

Comment: Try to simplify it to a 1 minute issue or so and that run it with the [10046 database trace](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/tgsql/performing-application-tracing.html#GUID-440D3AD4-B302-408E-8627-FE8032DD09F9). You will immedietely see what is the database doing, the rest is the network and you app...

Comment: Hi Marmite Bomber, I will check on given link, thanks.

Comment: @JustinCave, I am not executing and fetching data using procedure,  Batch wise insertion is used, We load file into staging then staging to main using procedure.